# Calling authentification feature from another feature

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

I'm starting learning automation test using selenuim webdriver & cucumber, I have tow features:

*Authentification.feature*

```
Feature: Authetification

    @Test1      
    Scenario: Authetification (credential)

    Given   Open the Url                
    When    Enter the Username and Password             
    Then    Click connect_btn
```

*CreateUser.feature*

```
Feature: Create User        

@Test2
Scenario: Create User

Given   Open users list             
When    Fill the form       
Then    Click save_btn
```

*How to call the authentification into CreateUser.feature ?*

Thanks & Regards,Patricia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber does not support calling one feature from another feature (or one step from another step).

From the [Cucumber docs - FAQ](https://cucumber.io/docs/community/faq/):

"**How do I call other steps or scenarios?**
Each scenario should be independent; you should be able to run them in any order or in parallel without one scenario interfering with another.

Each scenario should test exactly one thing so that when it fails, it fails for a clear reason. This means you wouldn’t reuse one scenario inside another scenario.

If your scenarios use the same or similar steps, or perform similar actions on your system, you can extract [helper methods](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/step-organization/#helper-methods) to do those things."

In your case, I'd recommend thinking about how to get your system to a state where a user is logged in at the start of any test where that is a precondition, without actually testing the login feature each time. That way if the login functionality breaks for any reason, you can still test other functionality of your application.